# How to return response from a go function coroutine

Tags: php, laravel, coroutine, swoole, openswoole

I'm using the Laravel Swoole Coroutine `go` function to do a HTTP request in order to achieve better performance. When I get the response from the external service, a new entry is created in the database with the data from the external service.

I want to be able to return a response from the controller with that new DB record. However, it appears that anything outside the `go` does not have access to anything that got assigned in the `go` function. I understand that that happens in a separate thread, but is there a way to implement this so that I can have access to the results inside the `go` function?

Please note that I have coroutine enabled globally and I only to use function as shown below:

```
public function store(User $user, Request $request) {
   go(function () {
       // get data from external API using Laravel HTTP Client
       ...
       $user = User:create($data);
       return response($user, 201)->send();
   });
}
```

I have tried using the `WaitGroup()`, but it complains that the event loop has already been started if I wrap it with the `Co\run` function.

Comment: Hey, thanks for posting a (in first glance) good formatted question! Could you add a link to the git page of the go coroutine in your question? That would be very helpfull :)

Comment: @RobBiermann thanks for the feedback :) I'm not sure what git page, you mean the full code of what I posted above?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I mean the  Laravel Swoole Coroutine. the go function does not exist in laravel so we don't know what it returns, hence it is harder to help. If we can see the source code for this function, we might be able to help

Comment: @RobBiermann That's the documentation: https://openswoole.com/docs/modules/swoole-coroutine-run

Comment: @RobBiermann And this is their GitHub page: https://github.com/openswoole/swoole-src

Comment: @RobBiermann This is the Laravel Swoole package I'm using: https://github.com/hhxsv5/laravel-s

Comment: Thanks! So I checked the docs and did some googling and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868369/what-happens-to-return-value-from-goroutine
So to be clear, I think you should not use subroutines if you want your return value. Subroutines are meant to run like a void function: It needs to do something, but you don't want a response. If you DO want the response, then the user needs to wait for the creation anyway. If your goal is to off-load user creation from this server to another server, an api call, directly in the `store` function, would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
co::run(function() {

    function a($par) {
        $ch = new Chan(1);

        go(function() use ($par, $ch) {
            $res = $par * 2;

            $ch->push($res);
        });

        $ret = $ch->pop();

        return $ret;
    }

    echo '='.a(3);
});
```